# CSS font squirrel not applying properly

Tags: css, fonts

I am using two fonts from font squirrel for this practice to style some of the my wordpress widget areas:Gothic and Playfair Display. But for some reason,only Playfair is being applyed and Gothic is being ignored.
Because its wordpress widget areas I cant actually display the html but basically the following is the CSS code which again works for one type font only:

CSS:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Playdisplay';
  src: url('font/PlayfairDisplay-Bold.ttf') format('ttf'),
     url('font/PlayfairDisplay-BlackItalic.ttf') format('ttf'),
     url('font/PlayfairDisplay-BoldItalic.ttf') format('ttf'),
     url('font/PlayfairDisplay-Italic.ttf') format('ttf'),
     url('PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf') format('ttf'),
     url('font/PlayfairDisplay-black.ttf') format('ttf');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;     
}
@font-face{
   font-family: 'Goth';
   src: url('font/GOTHIC.ttf') format('ttf'),
      url('font/GOTHICB.ttf') format('ttf'),
      url('font/GOTHICBI.ttf') format('ttf'),
      url('font/GOTHICI.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}

.mainfooter h3{
  font-family: Goth, GOTHIC; 
}

footer h1,
footer h2,
footer h3{
  font-family: Playdisplay, PlayfairDisplay-Bold;
}
```

How can I use both fonts and apply anywhere in the site?

Comment: The problem will be the link to your font file. You need to check where your font file is located to your CSS file. Just now it says your font folder sits inside your css folder beside this CSS file. Also why do you have 4 or more of the same formats. you only need it once, unless you are applying `WOFF` or some other format like that

Comment: I removed the format from all of them. The Gothic is now being accepted,but for the Playfair I am using  italic but it does not really work.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your font names in single quotes

```
.mainfooter h3{
  font-family: 'Goth'; 
}

footer h1,
footer h2,
footer h3{
  font-family: 'Playdisplay';
}
```

Also, you're using relative paths for your font files, check these are correct!

Comment: It does not really make a different effect. Like I mentioned in the question.The first font type ( Playdisplay )  works. I applied the them both the same and they are in the same folder.

Comment: If you remove or comment out the font code for the first font, leaving the second.. does it get applied then in your code?

Comment: Initially it was apparently a problem with the format so I removed all format(.ttf). Happened that now Gothic works, but hte h1,h2,h3 do not accept PlayfairDisplay any more.

Comment: Are you sure your CSS declarations are correct? Like, should it be `.footer` instead of `footer`?

Comment: Yes. cause am styling the footer tag directly.